# XSL Sorting within a loop

Tags: xml, sorting, loops, xslt

I need help on figuring out how I can sort the prices in the example below... for example, in ascending order. As you can see I have tried  but it doesn't work... i think because i am only getting certain elements that have a version number greater than or equal to 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match ="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Apps List</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Application List</h1>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Version</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- for loop start-->
                    <xsl:for-each select="app/appCategory">
                        <xsl:sort select="appType/@price" order="ascending" data-type="number" />
                        <xsl:variable name="appType" select="@type"/>
                            <!-- for loop start-->
                            <xsl:for-each select="appItem">
                                <!-- if statement start-->
                                <xsl:if test = "@version &#62;&#61; 1"> <!-- &#62;&#61; means >= -->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                                        <td><xsl:value-of select="$appType"/></td>
                                        <td><xsl:value-of select="@version"/></td>
                                        <td>&#xA3;<xsl:value-of select="@price"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO8859-1" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="q2.xsl"?>

<app>
    <appCategory type="Productivity">
        <appItem fileName="Messages" version="0.2" price="34.99">Thunderbird</appItem>
        <appItem fileName="Contacts" version="2.0" price="3.00">Convenience Book</appItem>
        <appItem fileName="Calendar" version="1.0" price="45.00">ForgetMilk</appItem>
        <appItem fileName="Email" version="1.3" price="3.45">Email</appItem>
    </appCategory>
    <appCategory type="Games">
        <appItem fileName="BrickBreaker" version="7.1" price="14.99">Brick Breaker</appItem>
        <appItem fileName="WordMole" version="4.1" price="22.99">Word Mole</appItem>
        <appItem fileName="FistOfAwesome" version="4.1" price="3.99">Fist of Awesome</appItem>      
    </appCategory>
    <appCategory type="Social networking">
        <appItem fileName="BlackBerry Messenger" version="0.2" price="0.99">Blackberry Messenger</appItem>
        <appItem fileName="Twitter" version="1.1" price="24.99">Twitter</appItem>
        <appItem fileName="Facebook" version="0.5" price="44.99">Facebook</appItem>
        <appItem fileName="Grodog" version="0.5" price="1.99">Grodog</appItem>
        <appItem fileName="LinkedIn" version="2.1" price="3.59">LinkedIn</appItem>
        <appItem fileName="YouTube" version="5.5" price="1.59">YouTube</appItem>
    </appCategory>
</app>
```

Comment: you would have to show us your xml source to figure out why it is not sorting correctly... btw &gt;= is the same as &#62;&#61; and is somewhat more readable... respectively you can use &lt; for lower than

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When used with `<xsl:for-each>`, the `<xsl:sort>` element(s) defining the sort key for the input sequence must appear as the first children of the for-each, and *they apply to the items selected by the enclosing for-each*.  The way your template is written now, it appears to be trying to sort `<appCategory>` elements on sort keys that consist of sequences of prices.  That is probably not what you want.

Also, your use of "appType" is confusing.  Is it indeed an element name in the source document, as the XSL seems to suggest, or is it only a variable name?  I'm guessing the latter.

It is difficult to be sure what you need without a schema for the document you are transforming.  I'm going to guess that an input document could have this form (which is more or less implied by your template):

```
<app>
  <appCategory type='type1'>
    <appItem version='0' price='2.00'>item1</appItem>
    <appItem version='1' price='1.00'>item1</appItem>
    <appItem version='1' price='2.00'>item2</appItem>
    <appItem version='2' price='2.50'>item2</appItem>
  </appCategory>
  <appCategory type='type2'>
    <appItem version='57' price='200.00'>item3</appItem>
  </appCategory>
</app>
```

In that case, if you want to sort `<appItem>` elements across all categories by price, then you need something more like this:

```
<!-- select all the items to be sorted and output -->
<xsl:for-each select="app/appCategory/appItem[@version &gt;= 1]">
  <!-- sort key for the input sequence selected by the for-each -->
  <xsl:sort select="@price" order="ascending" data-type="number" />
  <!-- sequence constructor for the transformed result -->
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="../@type"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@version"/></td>
    <td>&#xA3;<xsl:value-of select="@price"/></td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```